# Export features to pdf using JSPDF and Openlayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I built a map with different type of data, WMS layer, Vector Layers ( features extracted them from GeoJson file).

Used Technologies :
- Openlayers 3 
- JSPDF

How can i export just the selected feature from the map ? i parsed the whole of net asking about that, but without solution.